# Android App on Emulator does not show up the APP in the tray however it shows in the listed apps

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have been breaking my head on this.

When I run the app on Emulator it runs it normally and opens the Application however when I close the app or come out of it the application icon is found nowhere.

[When APP installs on the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpL65.png)

[When I come out of the app to app tray it's no where found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjA7p.png)

Here's my Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.shravan.todolist">

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent>
</queries>

<application
    android:name=".CustomApplicationClass"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.ToDoList"
    tools:targetApi="34">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <data android:scheme="todoapp" android:host="open" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <!-- Branch URI Scheme -->
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- REPLACE `android:scheme` with your Android URI scheme -->
            <data android:scheme="todoapp" android:host="open" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>`
```

When I run the app on Emulator it runs it normally and opens the Application however when I close the app or come out of it the application icon is found nowhere.

I am trying to test out a SDK integration on this simple APP but it refuses to install the application.